# CSS Background image position moving to center on larger browser windows

Tags: css

I cannot get the orange background behind DONATE at the bottom of my page right to stay put in larger browser windows. I have tried every css trick I can find. Please help!

Thanks,
Janet

http://dev30.ncld.org/

Comment: Can't understand the problem : what are you trying to achieve with the donate block in the footer ?

Comment: HTML/CSS please, perferably in a JSfiddle.

Comment: Please show us some code

Answer (score 0):

You missed this trick then:

```
#footer .footer-col-orange {
    margin-left: 790px; // adjust accordingly
    left: initial;
}
```

This will keep your donate box relative to the footer element, and not to the left page border and will work on all displays.

The other option is to set the position of `#footer .padding` element to relative.

Answer (score 0):

There you go :

```
#footer .padding {
/* padding: 15px 20px 0px 100px; */
width: 1010px;
/* position: absolute; */
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #0A6DA1;
padding-top: 15px;
position: relative; /* First part */
}

#footer .footer-col-orange {
position: absolute;
/* background-position: right; */
right: -2em; /* second part, feel free to put what you want */
}
```

*When you set a position: absolute; to an element, it will pull it out of the HTML flow, and you can give it coordinates (top, left, right; bottom). **This coordinates are relative to the first parent with a relative position**. As you didn't set any parent element to be the relative, you positioned your element relative to the document.*

Answer (score 0):

Your orange box is current positioned absolutely, as you know. This means that is is relative to the browser window. The left edge of that window, because you have `left:900px'. What we want is for it to be relative to the footer, which is centered.

To do this, we need to set the parent container of the orange box to `position:relative`. This will cause the orange box's position to depend on it's parent instead of the window.

```
#footer .padding {
    position:relative;
}
```

Then, it's just a matter of setting the yellow box to the right position. Given that it's on the right side, I'd delete the `left` value entirely and set `right:-45px` instead.

```
#footer .footer-col-orange {
    left:auto;
    right:-45px
}
```

With these, it'll line up perfectly with the edge of the white box above:

[image]

You are going to run into an issue with inline styling. You not only have your styles applied by CSS, they are duplicated inline. You're going to either need to set `!important` in the new CSS that I've provided (not best practice), or better, remove the inline styling. If you provide some more information about how your side is built (WordPress, HTML template, etc) I can help with removing the inline styling.